# How to predict the response variable of a speedlm model in R?

Tags: r, forecasting

I have just started using the `speedglm` package. I fitted a very simple model and tried to predict the response variable (`yhat`).

```
library(speedglm)

data<-data.table(x=1:10, y=5:14)

model<-speedlm(y~x, data=data)
```

In contrast to the lm function I cannot use the `predict(model)` to get the `yhat`. Is there any respective routine I can use for the `speedglm` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see there is no `predict` method. You sacrifice convenience for speed. However, it's quite easy to calculate the yhat values:

```
data[, yhat := c(cbind(1, x) %*% coef(model))]
#     x  y yhat
# 1:  1  5    5
# 2:  2  6    6
# 3:  3  7    7
# 4:  4  8    8
# 5:  5  9    9
# 6:  6 10   10
# 7:  7 11   11
# 8:  8 12   12
# 9:  9 13   13
#10: 10 14   14
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your instant response. You are absolutely right..convenience for speed! speedlm helped me drop the modelling time from one hour to 5 minutes keeping the exact coefficient estimates. Regards, Konstantinos